# Navigation Bar disappeared when rotate the device

Tags: objective-c

I have a project, which have relationship segue as photo below.Everything work fine. But When I rotate the device/ iOS simulator The Navigation Bar is disappeared. What happen ? Some setting I need to know ?

[LINK TO IMAGE](http://www.royalmassasje.com/test.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Navigation Controller properties in the interface builder, and make sure that `Hide Bar When Vertically Compact` is unchecked

[image]

Comment: You was born to be my angel Mahmoud Adam. Thanks for 2 times help. I almost pull my hair and hit my head to the table. Holy crap I spent whole for this.